# Not less than zero - make a variable which is less than zero to zero

Tags: php, zero

How can I make a variable that will not be less than zero? Like:

```
$var=(($add-$substract) || 0);
```

That works in JavaScript, but not in PHP. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: In php logical or will result in a boolean and not the value like in javascript

Comment: How would that make a variable that will "not be less than zero"?  `(-1-5)||0` in JavaScript is `-6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use ternary operators

```
$var = ($add-$subtract)>0?($add-$subtract):0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `($add-$subtract)>0`?

Comment: Shoot, yeah it should be, fixed

Comment: wondering that this reply is chosen. I like much more that reply below
$var = max(0, $add-$substract);

Comment: Probably because it's a matter of preference

Answer (score 24):

As far as you're concerned about integers, I find [`max`](http://php.net/max) handy:

```
$var = max(0, $add-$substract);
```

Answer (score 0):

($var=$add-$substract)<0 or $var=0;

Comment: This poorly formatted answer is missing its educational explanation. If you can imagine a new developer coming to this page for knowledge on this topic, you can be pretty sure that they have almost no understanding of the syntax or basic programming.  This means that your answer should probably break down the script to explain what it does and why.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).